# Convert array objects to just array values

Tags: javascript

I have some data (array with objects) that looks like the one below:

```
data = [
         {
           name: 'peter'
         },
         {
           name: 'paul'
         }
       ];
```

I need to convert the above data to this:

```
data = ['peter', 'paul'];
```

I've tried:

```
Object.values(data));
```

...but that didn't do the job.

How can I do this conversion?

Comment: As there's only one known property a simple `for` loop would be enough. Why did you choose `Object.values()`? And how did you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple `.map()` would do

```
var desiredResult = data.map(element => element.name);
```

Docs about [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Or even `data.map(({name}) => name);`

Comment: yeah, decostructing the object in the parameter itself is nice, I use it on react components for instance, but if OP is starting with the lang I prefer to keep it simple as possible